# Need help explaining something involving Global Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I'm trying to understand why the Corollary of the Global Continuity Theorem does not contradict the statement made after it.
[image: Page 151 Bartle's Elements of Real Analysis]

Comment: What is the contradiction you think is taking place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corollary states that a function is continuous if and only if the *pre-image* of any open set in the range is open. The statement after the corollary emphasizes the fact that this is unrelated to the question of whether the *image* of an open set in the domain is open.

Answer (score 1):

To emphasize the distinction between images and pre-images made by @Umberto P., think of a simple example: let $f: R \to R$ be defined by $f(x) = x^2$. Then one could show that $f$ is continuous (so by the corollary, conditions (a), (b), and (c) are all true). But note that, for example, $G:=(-1,1)$ is open, but $f(G) = [0,1)$ is not open.

Functions $f$ satisfying the condition that $f(G)$ is open for $G$ open are called *open maps*. This is a different notion from continuity.